# how to setup cowboy with rebar3

Tags: erlang, rebar, cowboy

I am a newbie of erlang/cowboy, using `rebar3` now, as 99's cowboy is using its own erlang.mk system, how can I use `rebar3` to build a cowboy `release`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `new` command to create your project.

```
$ rebar3 new app yourapp
```

Then in your project path find `rebar.config` file and add `cowboy` as dependencie under the `deps` key:

```
{deps, 
    [{cowboy, {git, "git://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git", {tag, "1.0.1"}}}]}.
```

Then using `compile` command rebar3 fetch defined dependencies and compile them as well as your application.

```
rebar3 compile
```

At the end for making a `release` you first need to create your release structure and then making a release with following commands.

```
$ rebar3 new release yourrel
$ rebar3 release
```

Note that [basic usage example](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/basic-usage) of Rebar3 is about cowboy in details.

Comment: the problem is more linked to, for example 
- handler.erl in cowboy

as handlers are created by eralng.mk system, how it be convert to `rebar3` template? Thank you in adavance.

Comment: I am in the same position as perigee (almost 4 years later). How do you import the cowboy package into "myrel_app.erl" and start putting routes together? Following the rebar3 and cowboy tutorials alone is not quite enough for erlang beginners looking for an easy win (Though, I've been working on reading LYSE for a month or more bit by bit). I'll keep trying to figure it out on my own and such, but for now, this answer is not sufficient.